# Why does xubuntu install loads of stuff when I only selected desktop?

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu

I have performed a few installs of Xubuntu (because its lighter than ubuntu) but am always annoyed by the fact Xubuntu installing loads of unwanted stuff (and thus taking a long time onto a usb) when I only select that I want the Xubuntu graphical deskop (in the checkbox list while installing).

How do I prevent Xubuntu from installing:

1. office applications
2. cd burning apps
3. music and media players
4. etc.

When all I want is the core system, plus a web browser and the dev tools?

Also is there any way to make a customized install so it sets up things like user name, domain etc, and other settings such as swappable upon install?

Comment: This question has been asked before, check this [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170579/minimal-install/).

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can actually choose, which packages get installed during the installation. There is some [LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch) if you want to make a custom Ubuntu install. But I would recommend to use some other lightweight distro like [Arch](http://www.archlinux.org)

Comment: I would use Arch, but I needed to have minimal hassle, and arch requires a lot of reading and config. I just wanted a GUI environment.

Comment: After you set it up its not really any hassle...and most packages work out of the box